# Postgres - detect change in JSONB column value from 'null' to some value across rows

Tags: postgresql, json

I have to work with a table that looks like this:

[image: fun_table]

The actual table is obviously much larger, but for sake of discussion, is there any way to elegantly query the difference between when `{ a: null }` turned into `{ a: "something"? }`

My instinct is to try something (probably pseudocode) like this:

```
select (select update_time as finish_time from fun_table where json_data -> 'a' != 'null' as tableA) 
       - (select update_time as start_time from fun_table where json_data -> 'a' = 'null as tableB) 
from tableA, tableB
```

But there are a lot of different JSON objects in the actual json_data..."b", "c", etc. So again, is there a better / cleaner way to find the difference between the timestamps when "a" turned from "null" to "something"?

Comment: No screen shots of text, ever.

Comment: Check [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) (see accepted answer)!

Answer (score -1):

JSONB supports equality checks. So, if you're using it, you need only

1. Create an `AFTER` trigger on

   ```
   CREATE TRIGGER foo
     AFTER UPDATE OF json_data
     ON myTable
     FOR EACH ROW
     WHEN (new.json_data IS DISTINCT FROM old.json_data)
     EXECUTE PROCEDURE myFunction;
   ```
2. Either,

   - Insert the `id`, and `new.update_time` into a new table, or
   - Update the `update_time` setting it the current time, and query later for `update_time` > `last_time_ran`.